# Java Swing Event Handling between classes

Tags: java

I have a main frame class, and 2 panel classes.

One of the panels has input fields
The second panel has buttons

I am trying to figure out how to set up event handling such that when a button in the second panel is clicked, I am able to perform an operation which requires accessing components (text field) from the first panel.

The problem is I am unable to access the components from a different class

Code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private InputPanel input_panel;
private ButtonPanel button_panel;

public MainFrame() {
   setTitle("Shop"); 
   setSize(650,350);
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   setResizable(false);
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   input_panel = new InputPanel();
   button_panel = new ButtonPanel();

   add(input_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   add(button_panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

   setVisible(true);
}
```

}

```
public class InputPanel extends JPanel {

private static JLabel item_num;
private static JLabel book_id;
private static JLabel quantity;
private static JLabel item_info;
private static JLabel subtotal;

private static JTextField t_item_num;
private static JTextField t_book_id;
private static JTextField t_quantity;
private static JTextField t_item_info;
private static JTextField t_subtotal;


public InputPanel() {

   //Layout Manager 
   FlowLayout flow_input_layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 75, 10);

   //Panel
   setLayout(flow_input_layout);
   setBackground(Color.yellow);

   //Text Fields and Labels
   item_num = new JLabel("Enter number of items in this order:");
   add(item_num);
   t_item_num = new JTextField(20);
   add(t_item_num);

   book_id = new JLabel("Enter Book ID for Item # 1:");
   add(book_id);
   t_book_id = new JTextField(20);
   add(t_book_id);

   quantity = new JLabel("Enter quantity for Item # 1:");
   add(quantity);
   t_quantity = new JTextField(20);
   add(t_quantity);

   item_info = new JLabel("Item # 1 Info:");
   add(item_info);
   t_item_info = new JTextField(20);
   add(t_item_info);

   subtotal = new JLabel("Order subtotal for X Items:");
   add(subtotal);
   t_subtotal = new JTextField(20);
   add(t_subtotal);
}
```

}

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private static JButton process_btn;
private static JButton confirm_btn;
private static JButton view_btn;
private static JButton finish_btn;
private static JButton new_btn;
private static JButton exit_btn;

public  ButtonPanel() {

   //Layout Manager
   FlowLayout flow_input_layout = new FlowLayout();

   //Button Panel
   setLayout(flow_input_layout);
   setBackground(Color.blue);

   //Buttons
   process_btn = new JButton("Process Item #1");
   process_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(process_btn);

   confirm_btn = new JButton("Confirm Item #1");
   confirm_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(confirm_btn);

   view_btn = new JButton("View Order");
   view_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(view_btn);

   finish_btn = new JButton("Finish Order");
   finish_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(finish_btn);

   new_btn = new JButton("New Order");
   new_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(new_btn);

   exit_btn = new JButton("Exit");
   exit_btn.addActionListener(this);
   add(exit_btn);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ;
}
```

}

Problem is I cannot access components from my other panel class. Not sure what to do

Comment: Observer pattern can help you on that. Google!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to add the InputPanel to the constructor of the ButtonPanel and then store it in a variable.

```
input_panel = new InputPanel();
button_panel = new ButtonPanel(input_panel);
```

And in the ButtonPanel:

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

...
private final InputPanel inputPanel;

public  ButtonPanel(final InputPanel inputPanel) {
    this.inputPanel = inputPanel;
    ...
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    this.inputPanel.getItemNum().doSomething() // you will need to also create accessor methods in the inputPanel
}
```

And btw you should be using camelCase in Java.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will also swap to camelCase thanks for the tip. For accessor methods do you mean getter method? Just making sure I have the right idea

Comment: Yes, I mean getters.

Comment: Hello, one final question. So my button has to access a component from my text input panel in order to make changes to the main frame. Should I also pass in the mainframe as a parameter to the button class? Would that be a bad thing to do considering that is meant to be my controller class? Thanks

Comment: You can do whatever works, but check out some articles about listeners and observer pattern or design patterns for Swing in general.